# Returning hrefs using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm working with html loosely structured like this:

```
...
   <div class='TL-dsdf2323...'>
      <a href='/link1/'>
         (more stuff)
      </a>
      <a href='/link2/'>
         (more stuff)
      </a>
   </div>
...
```

I want to be able to return all of the hrefs contained within this particular div. So far it seems like I am able to locate the proper div

`div = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@class, 'TL')]")`

This is where I'm hitting a wall though. I've gone through other posts and tried several options such as

`links = div.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'/link')]")`

and

`div.find_element_by_partial_link_text('/link')`

but I keep returning empty lists. Any idea where I'm going wrong here?

Edit:
here's a picture of the actual html. I simplified the div class name from ThumbnailLayout to TL and the href /listing to /link

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mr_mooo_cow pointed out in a comment, a delay was needed in order to extract the links. Here is the final working code:

```
a_tags = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located( (By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@href,'/listing')]") ))
links = []

for link in a_tags:
    links.append(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this:

```
links = div.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'/link') and ./div[starts-with(@class, 'TL')]]")
```

./ references the parent element in xpath. I haven't tested this so let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Just tried this out and received this error:

InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "//a[starts-with(@href,'/link')] and ./div[starts-with(@class, 'TL')]" is invalid: TypeError: Document.evaluate: Result type mismatch

Comment: Oh whoops I think my syntax was a little bit wrong. Try again please.

Comment: This also returned an empty list. I tried modifying it several ways too: (1) using driver.find instead of div.find and (2) by keeping div and removing the everything from 'and' on since the div should already have identified the class.

Is there any other information I can provide that would be useful?

Comment: Is your html snippet a direct copy paste from the source code? If not, can you post a direct copy paste so I can see the actual structure. Thanks!

Comment: Hey I added a close up screenshot of the div and a tags in question. If you want a more full view of the html let me know!

Comment: The class in the parent div element in the screenshot you posted doesn't match the conditions of your xpath. The class="Thumbnail..." and the criteria you are checking for is class starts with = "TL"

Comment: Yeah I just simplified for the sake of the post. I altered everything - including your code - on my end to have the correct class name and href.

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot without knowing the site and code. Is it possible the page is loading these elements later via javascript? If so, are you using a delay? Try adding a delay of a few seconds and using WebDriverWait

Comment: You could be right! I'm trying variations of this: links = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(lambda d: d.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'/listing')")) but no luck so far. The site I'm looking at is nbatopshot.com/search